# Fancybox "title" settings (outside/inside, null, top, ... ) + Tips and tricks

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I use Fancybox (3 beta), and title settings dont change anything, but other settings works for other attributes (thumbs, overlaycolor, ..).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
                padding: 0, 
                margin: 10,
                closeBtn  : true,
                helpers :   
                    {    
                        title: {
                            position: 'top',
                                },
                        thumbs:
                            {
                             width  : 40,
                             height : 40,
                            }
                        },
                beforeShow : function() {
                        var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');
                        this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
                        this.title = alt;
                    },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've also tried to set "alt" attribute of images as title for link, but it doesn't work at all. (But I'm not sure it's the right place to write the function)

[Test page](http://olouf.fr/test.php%20Test%20page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tips for Fancybox 3 dont work the same. Here is one to get the alt attribute from the image.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
beforeLoad : function() {
    this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');

    /*
        "this.element" refers to current element, so you can, for example, use the "alt" attribute of the image to store the title:
        this.title = $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt');
    */
}
});
```

From https://libraries.io/npm/fancybox/3.0.0